# Number of unique sequences of length 7, where elements are members of the digits 1 through 5, and repeated elements are allowed.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I need a little help with this practice problem of mine. I believe I am a little stuck on what it means by "unique" sequences. I know that if such a word wasn't there. The answer would merely be $5^7$.

Comment: $5^7$ is correct. +1 to your question for both attempting to *meta-cheat*, and actually posting the result of your meta-cheating attempt.  Here, I use meta-cheating to refer to attempting to enter the mind of the problem composer to determine why the adjective *unique* was used.  I had the advantage of knowing that $(5)^7$ must be correct, and therefore being able to reverse-engineer the problem composer's intent.  He intended that (for example) the number $1234545$ be considered distinct from the number $5432145$.  ...see next comment

Comment: In my opinion, once it is specified that repeated elements are allowed, and you are asked about forming distinct numbers, no answer other than $(5)^7$ is reasonable.  So,  once you are locked into that answer, it narrows the possible intentions of the problem composer, so reverse engineering the intent becomes easier.